# How to proceed validation without creating a new DTO (Data Transfer Object) in Plumier

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, plumier

I create a registration form contains password confirmation which is not part of the domain model. I don't want to make an extra DTO to just to make the validation work.

My domain model is like below:

```js
@collection()
export class User  {
    constructor(
        @val.unique()
        public username: string,
        @val.unique()
        @val.email()
        public email: string,
        public password: string,
        public role: UserRole,
        public firstName: string,
        public lastName: string,
        public gender: "Male" | "Female" | "Unspecified",
        public profilePicture:string | undefined,
        public dateOfBirth: Date,
    ) { }
}
```

My controller is just simply like below

```js
export class UsersController {
    @route.post("")
    save(data: User) {
        //save the data
    }
}
```

I know with Plumier you can crate your own custom validation but how do you do that without creating a new DTO (Data Transfer Object) represents the request body that contains `confirmPassword` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible,

```js
//custom validator
function confirmTheSame(){
    return val.custom(async (x, info) => {
        if(x !== info.ctx.request.body.password)
            return "Password not the same"
    }) 
}

//controller
export class UsersController {
    @route.post("")
    save(data: User, @confirmTheSame() confirmPassword:string) {
        //save the data
    }
}
```

Explanation:

1. [Name binding](https://plumierjs.com/docs/refs/parameter-binding#name-binding) (high priority), will assigned `confirmPassword` because its match with request body property.
2. [Model binding](https://plumierjs.com/docs/refs/parameter-binding#model-binding) (lower priority), will assigned `data` parameter with the request body
3. Plumier will not complains about missing field, thats why #2 works even if your `User` domain model doesn't contains `confirmPassword` property.